# Listing directory of images into dropdown and remembering selection

Tags: php

I have this code to list the images in a directory into a dropdown so that I can then select an image and save the image name selected into a flat file for later use in other programs/scripts. When I come back to make changes I have to re-select the image and I would like to be able to have it remember the image as selected via the variable.

It's been a while since I've been fluent in php as I've been undergoing medical treatments and the medicine has affected my memory and I've tried to work out an elseif statement but it wasn't successful, I think the while loop is overriding it. The functions file sorts the directory files and the info file is the flat file. It works, except it doesn't allow me to show the selected image in the dropdown menu when the page is reloaded.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
<?php

include ("functions.php");
include ("info_file1.php");

// Settings section ------------------------------

$filedir = "files/";                // The file folder
$columns = 1;                       // Number of columns of files listed per row
global $filename;
global $filename_sorted;

$i=0;
$j=0;
$k=0;
$m=0;

// Table Title row -------------------------------

echo "<select name=Image id=Image>";


if (file_exists($filedir)) {

    $handle = opendir($filedir); 

    while (false !==($file = readdir($handle)))
    { 
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") 
        {
        $filename[$i][1] = $file;
            $filename[$i][2] = date ("m/d/y", filemtime($filedir.$file));
            $filename[$i][3] = round(filesize($filedir.$file)/1024);
        ++$i;
        }
    }

    closedir($handle);


    // Sorting --------------------------------------------

    $filename_sorted = ($filename);

    // End of Sorting -------------------------------------

    while($m<(count($filename)))
    {
        echo "<option value=".$filename_sorted[$m][1].">".$filename_sorted[$m][1]."</option>";
 $m++;
    } 
} elseif ( $image=$filename_sorted[$m][1] )
   echo "<option value=".$image." selected>".$image."</option>";
else {
   echo "<option value=Upload Image First>Upload Image First</option>";
}

echo "</select>";

?>
```

Comment: You forgot to assign `selected` to it in the code

Comment: That wasn't part of my edit, that's me telling you why you aren't seeing a value selected; you're not ever indicating which one it should be.

Comment: I understand, I corrected that on my end, and will edit it, still does not work. I thought I corrected it before I submitted the questions. I was thank you for the editorial changes.

Comment: 1. Do you want it to show the same image for all the user, or that every user will chose for himself? 2. On this line `if ($image=$filename_sorted[$m][1] )` You're addressing `$filename_sorted` but it seems like it's not defined on that scope.

Comment: I want it to show the list of images in the dropdown, but defaulting to the selected image as defined in the variable. I tried this and it of course bypasses the while loop. I think I need to wait till I'm off of some of the meds so my mind is clear. Thanks for the input.

if ( $filename=$image )
   echo "<option value=".$image." selected>".$image."</option>";
while($m<(count($filename)))
{
 echo "<option value=".$filename_sorted[$m][1].">".$filename_sorted[$m][1]."</option>";
 $m++;
} 
} else {
   echo "<option value=Upload Image First>Upload Image First</option>";
}

echo "</select>";